# Dense Vector - Similarity Function

Tags: solr, cosine-similarity

I have configured `SOLR 9` with dense vector search.
For now I am using the cosine similarity function. But Is there any way I can override the existing function or write a custom method to give a high score to the latest documents.

Also `KNN` Query Parser returns `topK` results matched with the input, but is there anyway possible we can get all documents for which similarity score is greater than a specific number?

Checked `SOLR` documentation to find a similarity function suitable with the requirement.